Read is blocked by getc
For the following code:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[6];

    printf("%c\n", (char)getc(stdin));
    int ret = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 5);
    printf("%d\n", ret);
    printf("%c\n", (char)getc(stdin));
}

When using "abcdef" as the input, the system outputs
a
0
b

I think this means that read cannot get anything in this case. However, when comment out the first getc call, the system outputs
5
f

I think this means that read can get something.
My question is: how to avoid the block of read from getc?
BTW: you can re-pro the behavior from https://godbolt.org/z/EaPTMWPz9

Well, it is one of the reasons input/output methods tofrom/to the same stream shouldn't be mixed. Is there any practical reason to do so?

The only way to prevent getc from blocking on a read is to either provide data on the pipe, or close the pipe.  (Or cause a read error, or mark the fd non-blocking).  But I don't think that's really the question.  The behavior you're seeing is expected and reasonable; what exactly are you trying to do?  Is there something about the observed behavior that is confusing?

I realized they don't mean "blocked" like "blocking I/O", it confused me too. They're just asking why read isn't getting the data they expected it to.

Not the issue, but read returns an ssize_t, not an int. (When you switch, you'll also have to switch the format specifier to %zd.)

This is just a question about buffering.  The first getc reads a lot more than one byte from the file.  Note, "file" here is ambiguous, as there are several layers of abstraction, but I don't want to worry about the details.
Basically, reading from a file is slow, and the system makes things faster by doing slow things as rarely as possible.  When you call getc the first time, the system reads a bunch of data from the underlying stream, something like 4096 or 8192 bytes, or some reasonable size for the platform.  Calling read after getc returns 0, because the system already read all of the data.  The next getc returns data from the buffer that was written by the first getc.
If you call read before you call getc, then no data has been buffered and is still available to be read.
Basically, calling read attempts to bypass the buffering that getc is doing.

I like your answer because it tells why buffered IO is done. But you don't specifically say that you must not mix standard c library buffered I/O with POSIX I/O (read/write). You should say that. Also, it might be helpful to mention that whereas standard c library I/O can be found on many non-Unix platforms (e.g. Windows), POSIX is not as common on non-Unix OSes (e.g. Windows).

@StreveFord generally answers try not to be duplicative. If one answer has already covered not mixing I/O, it's generally not required to duplicate that information in every answer.  Otherwise all answers on SO would simply be copies of all previous answers plus some new thought.

getc isn't blocking anything. getc is buffered input. It read the whole string from STDIN_FILENO into a buffer associated with stdin first, and then just returns one character from the buffer each time you call it, until empty.
read is a POSIX function, not a standard part of the C language, and operates on the underlying file descriptors. It's a non-portable platform detail. In this case it's connected via STDIN_FILENO to the input (eg, a pipe if you ran echo "abcdef" | ./a.out), which has nothing left in it, because getc already read everything into stdin's internal buffer.
Either

use C buffered stdio such as fread(..., stdin) with fgetc(stdin), and let it manage buffering for you, OR
use POSIX or other platform-specific raw I/O and manage your own buffers.

Just don't mix them for the same stream, it fails in exactly the way you observed.

NB. The reason for the comment about blocking is that blocking vs. non-blocking I/O is a specific topic which is completely out of scope here, but the wording is similar enough to be a little confusing.

What do you mean by, "In this case it's connected to a pipe..."? Do you mean specifically that godbolt implements its input via a pipe? Or in general stdin is implemented via a pipe?

I was working for some reason on the assumption that OP was running echo "abcdef" | ./a.out or similar, but I can't remember why. Will clarify.

Per POSIX 2.5.1 Interaction of File Descriptors and Standard I/O Streams:

This section describes the interaction of file descriptors and standard I/O streams. The functionality described in this section is an extension to the ISO C standard ...
...
The result of function calls involving any one handle (the "active handle") is defined elsewhere in this volume of POSIX.1-2017, but if two or more handles are used, and any one of them is a stream, the application shall ensure that their actions are coordinated as described below. If this is not done, the result is undefined.

After that, there is a long list of rules that must be followed lest undefined behavior is invoked.
None of those rules involve reading from the same source via a file descriptor and a FILE * stream.
Thus undefined behavior is invoked when you try to read from the same underlying source via [p]read() in a file descriptor and also read from the same source via a FILE * stream like getc(stdin).

I understand the concept behind, "this is undefined behavior, so don't waste your time wondering why you see what you see - it could just as easily result in a unicorn jumping out of your screen." But the explanations in other answers provide useful insight on how these layers work. I think a combination of the two is best: tell what is really happening, and then say not to count on that behavior because it is undefined.

@StreveFord There was no point in repeating the other answer(s).  Understanding undefined behavior may be interesting, but it's effectively impossible to apply that understanding in any way that's reliable.  And if it's not reliable, it's worse than useless - it's dangerous.  Just because a unicorn won't be jumping out of your screen doesn't mean you have any control over what happens.  If could work fine, and with no changes fail the next time you run it.  That's an awfully low standard to write code to.


I think this means that read cannot get anything in this case. However, when comment out the first getc call, the system outputs.

This is what happens:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[6];

    printf("%c\n", (char)getc(stdin));

getc(stdin) is called to get a single character.  As you are calling a function of the package stdio (buffered input) this makes getc() to call read() to do a full buffer fill, reading all input available.
    int ret = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 5);

When read is called after get(), no input is available as all the input has been read and put in the buffer of stdin so read() blocks waiting for new input.  (I guess no more imput is available, for the reason stated below)
    printf("%d\n", ret);

Probably, you don't say, but there's no more input, as it was exhausted in the first get() call and is all awaiting in the buffer of stdin.  This makes read to return 0 bytes as input, as all the bytes available got to the buffer.
    printf("%c\n", (char)getc(stdin));

Now you call getc() again, which uses the buffer of stdin to get a new character, this time is 'b', and prints it.  getc() will continue to return chars from stdin buffer as long as the buffer doesn't get empty.
}

You can continue making calls to get() until the buffer empties, and then the next get() call will stop the program again (in a new call to read() to fill the buffer again)
In general, is a bad idea mixing calls to buffered stdio package calls with lowlevel system calls like read() (in which no buffering is done), because you don't normally know the size of the buffer (e.g. FreeBSD uses typical buffer sizes of 16kb on filesystem files, other systems use 4k, or even smaller buffers)
